# how to convert date object from timestamp to date without converting into String in json

Tags: java, json, date, spring-boot

I am using JDBC Template to get the values from the DB ,and storing the result in List> as the number of columns returned by my Template is not fixed.

So if there is any date field coming in the output , while setting it into the json variable of List> am getting the date printed as Timestamp in the output , but I need the date to get printed .

Tried using Object mapper and setting the date format using simple date formatter , but while setting into JSON it is again taking as a timestamp.

Since this is an Object that too we 'll begetting it dynamically , so I cant judge when there'll be date coming in my output.

Comment: Please show to code you are *talking* about

Comment: In JSON you'll **have** to serialize your date to some other format, which is usually either a string (ISO 8601) or a number (UNIX timestamp). To parse it to `Date`s in JavaScript, I usually write a function that recurses through the entire object, looks if the given string is an ISO 8601 timestamp (by using a regular expression) and then I automatically convert all those string to `Date`s.

Comment: Tips: [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) & [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 2):

JSON doesn't support Date objects it only supports Number, String, Boolean, and Array of those items.

So you will have to either do it as a formatted String already in the format you require or do it as a timestamp Number and then format through some type of library.

For JavaScript I use moment.js and for C# and Java I use the standard date and calendar objects available for those languages.